# xlrd crashes when reading .xls file modified by PHPExcel

Tags: php, python, phpexcel, xlrd

I'm having an extremely difficult time editing some Excel files using PHP and python.

I originally did everything in PHP using PHPExcel, but I was processing very large files and PHPExcel crashed when it ran out of memory. So I changed it to do some work using PHP and do the rest using python.

So the process is:

- Parse xml posted to PHP script
- Insert rows into Excel (.xls) file based on xml data
- Pass (.xls) file and xml data to python script to populate the spreadsheet
- ex. `python upload.py Example.xls data.xml` called by PHP
- python script uses xlrd, xlwt and xlutils to populate Excel file

The problem I'm having is that if the python script modifies a regular .xls file that I created by hand, it works perfectly. But once PHP excel modifies the Excel file, the python script produces the following error:

```
_locate_stream(Workbook): seen
  0  5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
 20  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
100= 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
120  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 2 
File "upload.py", line 63, in <module>
workbook_readonly = open_workbook(excel,formatting_info=True,on_demand=True)
File "/home/student/eamorde/public_html/dining/xlrd/__init__.py", line 435, in open_workbook
ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
File "/home/student/eamorde/public_html/dining/xlrd/book.py", line 87, in open_workbook_xls
ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
File "/home/student/eamorde/public_html/dining/xlrd/book.py", line 619, in biff2_8_load
cd.locate_named_stream(UNICODE_LITERAL(qname))
File "/home/student/eamorde/public_html/dining/xlrd/compdoc.py", line 390, in locate_named_stream
d.tot_size, qname, d.DID+6)
File "/home/student/eamorde/public_html/dining/xlrd/compdoc.py", line 418, in _locate_stream
raise CompDocError("%s corruption: seen[%d] == %d" % (qname, s, self.seen[s]))
xlrd.compdoc.CompDocError: Workbook corruption: seen[2] == 4
```

So I dug through the source code of xlrd and found the line that is producing the error:

```
def _locate_stream(self, mem, base, sat, sec_size, start_sid, expected_stream_size, qname, seen_id):
    # print >> self.logfile, "_locate_stream", base, sec_size, start_sid, expected_stream_size
    s = start_sid
    if s < 0:
        raise CompDocError("_locate_stream: start_sid (%d) is -ve" % start_sid)
    p = -99 # dummy previous SID
    start_pos = -9999
    end_pos = -8888
    slices = []
    tot_found = 0
    found_limit = (expected_stream_size + sec_size - 1) // sec_size
    while s >= 0:
        if self.seen[s]:
            print("_locate_stream(%s): seen" % qname, file=self.logfile); dump_list(self.seen, 20, self.logfile)
            raise CompDocError("%s corruption: seen[%d] == %d" % (qname, s, self.seen[s]))
```

The last line is the one raising the exception:

```
raise CompDocError("%s corruption: seen[%d] == %d" % (qname, s, self.seen[s]))
```

Can anyone explain this? The file is not corrupted in that opening it in Excel works fine, but xlrd seems to be unable to read it.

My PHP script does the following (rough sketch):

```
$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();
$file = "MyFile.xls";
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$phpExcel = $reader->load($file);
//(... insert rows based on xml)
$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5();
$writer->save('MyFile.xls');
exec("python upload.py MyFile.xls data.xml");
```

If anyone knows why this might be happening or even a better solution to my problems (PHPExcel memory issues) it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The source code for the file that's raising the error can be found [here](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/compdoc.py#L418).

Edit: I created an example, basically took my excel file and removed any identifying information. To try it yourself, see the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/amorde/6167193).

Comment: It raises the exception only when `self.seen[s]:` evaluates to `True`.  So print out `self.seen[s]` and `s` and see where in the file it is choking.  Then update your question with those details.

Comment: Do you mean modify the xlrd file to do that? And s is 2, if you look at the error it shows `Workbook corruption: seen[2] == 4`

Comment: The statement right below `if self.seen[2]:` printed out the following: `0  5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
   20  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
  100= 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
  120  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 2 ` But that's hard to read here, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Ah.  I missed that `xlrd` prints the info.  You'll need to start mucking around with `xlrd` to debug it.  It may be that the Excel file is not valid, but Excel is smart enough to open it anyway.  This will end up falling into a no-man's land between `xlrd` and `phpexcel`.  I don't know how motiviated developers will be to look into it, but you may want to create a small example and file a bug report.

Comment: I don't think I will be able to debug it myself, I'm extremely new to python and the xlrd source code is not very easy to follow. But I will look into creating a bug report, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Are there any news on the problem? Could you please upload this excel somewhere for testing and debugging?

Comment: After trying to solve this problem for a long time, I ended up just allocating more memory to the sloppy PHP script. I wish I could figure out a way to do it in Python, but it was too much of a hassle and I had a deadline to meet. My situation was very specific, though, so I'm not sure if I could create a good example that others could test

Comment: @EricAmorde do you have a sample file that shows the problem with xlrd?

Comment: I just started to look at this problem again, will hopefully have a sample file and php/python program that can recreate the problem within the next day or two.

Comment: @Nirk I created a test program that others can try, [link to gist](https://gist.github.com/amorde/6167193)

Comment: @EricAmorde this appears to be a PHPExcel issue.  I checked [with another parser](https://github.com/niggler/js-xls) and it sees the same issue as xlrd.  Long story short, the file uses a container format called [CFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format) and the table does not seem consistent with the standard.  Excel must be somehow robust to those issues

Comment: @Nirk Thanks for the input. I assumed that was the case, as I have also tried using the [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/index.html) with `.xlsx` files and the formatting gets messed up in between them, though it does work. Do you know of any other library that can insert rows? I might have to resort to creating the entire file from scratch if I want to use python.

Comment: Also, is thing something I should submit a bug report for? I can't imagine many people falling into the same situation as me.

Comment: @EricAmorde I see the same issue for a blank file.  I suspect the PHPExcel people can tell you more, especially since their parser seems to handle the file properly.

Comment: @EricAmorde btw openpyxl only handles xlsx, not xls

Comment: @Nirk Right, I actually want to use xlsx files, only tried xls to use xlrd/xlwt. But even using xlsx files with openpyxl, PHPExcel seems to introduce problems when inserting rows.

Comment: @EricAmorde Does your python program choke when *opening* the file or when performing the *writing* of "Hello, World"?

Comment: The python portion will fail to execute when loading the post-PHPExcel XLS/XLSX file because it detects corruption. I've tried xlrd/xlwt and openpyxl with no luck. I ended up generating the whole file from scratch using [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: reading with olefile worked for me, as described here http://www.crimulus.com/2013/09/19/reading-compound-file-binary-format-files-generated-by-phpexcel-with-pythondjango-xlrd/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got same error with one of my `.xls` files (excel can open them just fine, but xlrd fails). As I guess `Compdoc.seen` array keeps track of already read "FAT" sectors. In my case Root Entry reading block (SSCS) gets all that sectors marked as seen, leading to exception raise in future. U can try to find the bug in sectors reading logic and contribute to xlrd :) or just comment this lines with exception raise which will likely solve problem in your case (As did in mine) and wait for xlrd update.

Comment: The problem is it's not xlrd, it's PHPExcel. Check out the comment thread on my question - I've tested it using both xls and xlsx files with two different python excel libraries and another SO user tested it with a javascript xls parser and the same corruption appears on all of them. I tried looking at PHPExcels insert row function, but it's a bit over my head. I might take another look though.

Comment: Probably u should avoid using PHPExcel and let python xlrd do all the job. Just pass your input data to python from the very beginning. As for modifying files probably the best way is to read data from existing file and create the new one and paste your data. Do not modify - thats tricky.

Comment: Yes, as I stated in another comment, I have since moved to using xlsx-writer to generate the file from scratch. I no longer use PHPExcel or modify any existing files.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in a bind where you need data from a remote service, it's a hack, but commenting out line 419 (`raise CompDocError("%s corruption: seen[%d] == %d" % (qname, s, self.seen[s]))`) in `compdoc.py` seems to work okay.